# Do not understand message received after running temperature convert program

Tags: c, xcode

I am new to C and trying to write a program using Xcode that takes the temperature in Fahrenheit and converts it to Celsius, and vise versa.  My code so far is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hw2.h"

void convert_temp(int degree1, char scale1, int* degree2, char* scale2){

    if (scale1 == 'F') {
        *degree2 = ((degree1 - 32) * 5) / 9;
        *scale2 = 'C';
    }
    else {

        *degree2 = ((degree1 * 9) / 5) + 32;
        *scale2 = 'F';
    }
}

int main() {
    int degree1, degree2;
    char scale1, scale2;
    printf("Enter a temperature and a scale\n");
    scanf("%d %c", &degree1, &scale1);
    convert_temp(degree1, scale1, &degree2, &scale2);
    printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degree1, scale1, degree2, scale2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of correct i/o:

```
Enter a temperature and a scale
32 F
32 F = 0 C
```

However, when I run the code, this is what I get:

```
Enter a temperature and a scale
32 F
hw2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)
```

I cannot understand the output I am getting.  Can anybody tell me why I do not get `32 F = 0 C` on my output?  Everything in my code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `hw2` is the name of your program, then the debugger is complaining that it was compiled with optimisations turned on, which isn't normal during development, as the optimizer does all sorts of clever things to get the program running faster.

You need to do the following in Xcode:

- Ensure you are debugging using the `Debug` build configuration (Check your Schemes).
- Ensure you haven't turned on Optimizations for the `Debug` build configuration (Check your Build Settings).

Comment: I've got debugging switched to "Release" for Run, Test, Profile, Analyze, and Archive.  I thought this would turn debugging off and hence solve the problem altogether.  Perhaps I am mistaken?

Comment: @OmarN That's the issue then.  Put it back to `Debug`.  You want debugging turned on all the time you are developing and counter-intuitively "Running" actually means "Debugging" in Xcode.

Comment: The issue with that is then I just get a message saying `(lldb)` and I am not sure what that means :/

Comment: Oh, interesting...once I get the `(lldb)` message, if I go up to the Debug menu and choose Continue, THEN the program gives the expected output.  Strange, is there a way to just run the program without having to do that?

Comment: I don't understand why it's stopping, unless you have set a breakpoint?

Comment: Ah, yes, that was it!  Now it works.  Thank you so much trojanfoe!  This is my second day using Xcode, so lots to learn I guess.  Thank you!